# TideSDK Resize UI Window on focus/unfocus event

Tags: user-interface, tidesdk

I am very new to TideSDK and have changed the hello-world example in order to get a simple App running.
Now I would like to add the functionality to resize the window of my app to 500 x 300 pixels if the user switches to another app. In case it is the active app again the windows should resize to its original size again (500 x 950 in this case).

Apart from this I wonder if it is possible to have the app in foreground all the time somehow?

Since I am really new to this, any hints where to start/search/implement something is well appreciated.

Thanks in advance and best regards
pago

Answer (score 2):

you wanna look at the getting started guide: http://tidesdk.multipart.net/docs/user-dev/generated/#!/guide/getting_started

the section related to tiapp.xml would give you what you need !!

Answer (score 1):

thanks for the advise. it was the documentation that helped me, though. in the app.js I could include the event listeners:

```
var appWindow = Ti.UI.getCurrentWindow();

appWindow.addEventListener(Ti.FOCUSED, function(){
    appWindow.setHeight(950);
});

appWindow.addEventListener(Ti.UNFOCUSED, function(){
   appWindow.setHeight(95);
});
```